# How can I distribute a mix of Objective-C and Swift code to be run on the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, swift

I have a set of Swift and Objective-C files that extend some of the functionality in the XCTest framework.

I was easily able to create a Cocoa framework composed of these files. I added all the files to an OS X framework target and, since some of them import XCTest headers, I linked `XCTest.framework` to my framework. Users are able to add the framework to their unit test targets, provided they are building for OS X.

**Question:** How can I do the same (i.e.: distribute this code) for users building for the iOS simulator?

### What I've Tried (1): Cocoa Touch framework

I can't make a Cocoa Touch framework that imports `XCTest.framework`--doing so results in the following linker error ("Quick" is the name of the framework):

```
Ld /Users/modocache/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Quick-cajmiuprocunntdhiwsnsfzqydkc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Quick-iOS.framework/Quick-iOS normal x86_64
    cd /Users/modocache/GitHub/modocache/Quick
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/modocache/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Quick-cajmiuprocunntdhiwsnsfzqydkc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/modocache/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Quick-cajmiuprocunntdhiwsnsfzqydkc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/modocache/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Quick-cajmiuprocunntdhiwsnsfzqydkc/Build/Intermediates/Quick.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Quick-iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Quick-iOS.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/Quick-iOS.framework/Quick-iOS -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -framework XCTest -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/modocache/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Quick-cajmiuprocunntdhiwsnsfzqydkc/Build/Intermediates/Quick.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Quick-iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Quick-iOS_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/modocache/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Quick-cajmiuprocunntdhiwsnsfzqydkc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Quick-iOS.framework/Quick-iOS

ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

### What I've Tried (2): Cocoa Touch static library

Other projects similar to mine that extend the XCTest framework use static libraries to distribute their code. However, attempting to build a static library that includes Swift code results in the following error:

```
Libtool /Users/MBP-006FYGC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Quick-chbdhbmwzcgjlyfsbxuvmajagydy/Build/Products/Debug/libQuick-OSX.a normal x86_64
    cd /Users/MBP-006FYGC/GitHub/modocache/Quick
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7
    /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/MBP-006FYGC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Quick-chbdhbmwzcgjlyfsbxuvmajagydy/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/MBP-006FYGC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Quick-chbdhbmwzcgjlyfsbxuvmajagydy/Build/Intermediates/Quick.build/Debug/Quick-OSX.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Quick-OSX.LinkFileList -ObjC -L/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx -Xlinker -force_load -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_macosx.a -Xlinker -sectalign -Xlinker __SWIFT -Xlinker __ast -Xlinker 4 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __SWIFT -Xlinker __ast -Xlinker /Users/MBP-006FYGC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Quick-chbdhbmwzcgjlyfsbxuvmajagydy/Build/Intermediates/Quick.build/Debug/Quick-OSX.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Quick_OSX.swiftmodule -framework XCTest -framework Foundation -o /Users/MBP-006FYGC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Quick-chbdhbmwzcgjlyfsbxuvmajagydy/Build/Products/Debug/libQuick-OSX.a

error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker
Usage: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-sacLT] [-no_warning_for_no_symbols]
Usage: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -dynamic [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-o output] [-install_name name] [-compatibility_version #] [-current_version #] [-seg1addr 0x#] [-segs_read_only_addr 0x#] [-segs_read_write_addr 0x#] [-seg_addr_table <filename>] [-seg_addr_table_filename <file_system_path>] [-all_load] [-noall_load]
```

### More Information

For those that are interested, or if you need more details, the project in question is [on GitHub](https://github.com/modocache/Quick). I'm keeping track of what I've tried so far using [this issue](https://github.com/Quick/Quick/issues/5).

How can I distribute this Swift/Objective-C code (which uses XCTest code) to users who wish to use it in their iOS unit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the value of `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` in your project? I just created a fresh iOS framework and this was the default:

```
$(inherited) $(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR)
```

Try this instead:

```
$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks $(inherited) $(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR)
```

This should cause Xcode to find the iOS framework bundle before the Mac version.